# Compute the complex integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let, $f(z)$ be an analytic function. Then the value of $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f\bigl(e^{it}\bigr)\cos t dt= ?$$

(a) 0

(b) $2\pi f(0)$

(c)  $2\pi f'(0)$

(d)  $\pi f(0)$.

$\mathcal{My}{Attemt}:$

> First I put $e^{it}=z$. Then integration becomes $$\int_{|z|=1}f(z)\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\frac{dz}{iz}$$
>
> $$=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)(z^{2}+1)}{z^{2}}dz$$
>
> $$\frac{1}{2i}2\pi if'(0)=\pi f'(0)$$

But the answer does not match any option. Where my mistake??

Comment: What's the full question? I mean is this the complete statement of the question?

Comment: I think the last option has a typo.

Comment: By the way your work is correct.